# Missing first row of data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch, associative-array

I wrote a php script where I return restaurant name, address, phone number, table of store hours and a link to custom menu. However, even if in the database there is an entry for Monday hours it is not showing up when I do a while loop in the mysqli_fetch_assoc. Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("root","");
$rest_id2=$_GET['id'];
$rest_id=(int)$rest_id2;
var_dump($rest_id);
$sql="SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE restaurant_id='".$rest_id."'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo '<strong>'. "Restaurant name:". '</strong><br><br>';
echo $rows['restaurant_name'];
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<strong>Address: </strong><br><br>";
echo $rows['address_1']." ".$rows['address_2']." ". $rows['city']. ", ". 
$rows['state']. " ". $rows['zip']. "<br><br>";
echo '<strong>'. "Phone number:". '</strong><br><br>';
echo $rows['phone_number']. "<br><br>";
//hours table
$sql2="SELECT * from hours WHERE restaurant_id='".$rest_id."'";
$result2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'><tr><th>Open or Closed</th> . 
<th>Day</th><th>Start Time</th><th>End Time</th></tr>";
$num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result2);
// var_dump($num_rows);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    // var_dump($rows);
    if ($num_rows==0){
        echo "No hours data available";
    }
    elseif($row['day']=="Closed"){
        echo "<td><strong>". $row['day']. "</td></strong><br>";
        echo "<td><strong>". $row['open_closed']. "</td></strong><br>";
        echo "<td><strong>". "-". "</td></strong><br>";
        echo "<td><strong>". "-". "</td></tr></strong><br>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<tr><td><strong>". $row['day']. "</td></strong><br>";
        echo "<td><strong>". $row['open_closed']. "</td></strong><br>";
        echo "<td><strong>". $row['start_time']. "</td></strong><br>";
        echo "<td><strong>". $row['end_time']. "</td></tr></strong><br>";
    }
  }
   echo '<a href="' . "custom_menu.php?id=" .$rows['restaurant_id']. '"'. 
   '>'."<strong>Menu specialized for you</strong>" . '<br>'. '</a>';
   ?>
```

Have also provided what I am seeing in the website. Does anyone know why this is happening?

- Hours table screenshot from my db
  [image: Hours table screenshot from my db]
- db entries for restaurant hours being printed
  [image: db entries for restaurant hours being printed]
- hours table being printed through php example 2
  [image: hours table being printed through php example 2]

Comment: hard to answer without seeing what's in the table and the table structure

Comment: just added table structure and what is being printed out through php

Comment: Maybe the menu for monday has allergens. Just guessing because I don't know what's on those tables :D

Comment: Sorry I uploaded the code from the wrong script! It is the right code now

Comment: Just didn't provide the part where php is printing the restaurant name, address, phone number in the screenshots

Comment: You started to echo your `$rows` variable before the `while` loop. So your loop will fetch data from the second record on.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove line 21 from your code:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
```

It fetches the first row **before** the `while` loop fetches the rest of the records.

### Why?

Outside of the `while` loop you call 1st row and did not print it. This row is missing in output.